# Symbolic expansion of complex arithmetic expressions

Tags: complex-numbers, symbolic-computation

I have a lengthy complex polynomial-type equation. There is a software that can solve this type of equations provided I pass it as a coupled system of two real-valued equations. Hence, I am wondering if there is an automated way or software to do this?

Note that this may seem trivial to work out manually, but for lenghty equations with complex coefficients this becomes really tedious and error prone.

Here is an example. Let $$x = a+bi, y = c+di, z = e+fi \in \mathbb{C}$$, where  $a,b,c,d,e,f \in \mathbb{R}$.

For instance, the equation $xyz = s$ can be split as $$ace-bde-bcf-adf=Re(s) \\ acf-bdf+bce+ade=Im(s)$$

Already for the triple product above the split equations are not obvious. I have much more complicated one. Ideally, I need a software or an algorithm which would give me those $Re(\cdot), Im(\cdot)$.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you think about using Software like Matlab, Octave or freemat? I never worked with the later, but it looks very promising for what you want to do. I never used the other two to handle complex numbers, either. EDIT: I may have misunderstood your question. Do you need the result of "Re(s)" or do you need the formula? - Again this should be a comment, I know..

Answer (score 1):

This thing is called rectangular expansion of a complex expression.

MuPAD implements [this](http://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/rectform.html).
Mathematica as [well](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html).